# fundamental matrix solution for difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, transition-matrix, discrete-calculus

I need your help please, 
we have the system X(t+1)= \begin{bmatrix} -1 & \frac{2+(-1)^{t}}{2} \\ \frac{2+(-1)^{t}}{2} & -1 \end{bmatrix} X(t)

By using this formula $\phi(t)=A(t-1)...A(1)A(0)$ , with A(t) is the matrix given in the system

I must prove that $\phi(t)=\frac{1}{2^{t+1}}\begin{bmatrix}(\sqrt{3})^{t}+ (-\sqrt{3})^{t} & (\sqrt{3})^{t+1}+ (-\sqrt{3})^{t+1} \\
(\sqrt{3})^{t+1}+ (-\sqrt{3})^{t+1} & (\sqrt{3})^{t}+ (-\sqrt{3})^{t} \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a typo somewhere, the last identity is not true. If $X(t +1) = A(t) X(t)$, then

$$
A(0) = \begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{-1} & 1 \\ 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix},
$$

and

$$
\phi(1) = A(0) = \begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{0} & \bullet \\ \bullet & \bullet
\end{pmatrix}
$$

even without evaluating the remaining components you see that there's a problem